Solving the marginal likelihood integral and approximating closed-form solutions for that
Given the likelihood function:
\[ p_{y_s|r_s,x}(y_s|r_s,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(y_s - \alpha \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4})^2}{2}} \]
and the prior distribution for \( r_s \):
\[ p_{r_s}(r_s) = \lambda e^{-\lambda r_s} \]
The integral to be solved is:
\[ p_{y_s|x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} p_{y_s|r_s,x}(y_s|r_s,x) \cdot p_{r_s}(r_s) \, dr_s \]
Substituting the PDFs:
\[ p_{y_s|x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(y_s - \alpha \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4})^2}{2}} \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda r_s} \, dr_s \]
\[ = \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(y_s - \alpha \frac{\rho_s}{r_s^4})^2}{2}} e^{-\lambda r_s} \, dr_s \]
This integral represents the marginal likelihood $ p_{y_s|x} $. To solve it, you may need to apply techniques such as completing the square, integration by parts, or other methods suitable for handling Gaussian and exponential integrals.
Once the integral is solved, you'll have an expression for $ p_{y_s|x} $ that depends on $ y_s $ and $ x $, which can be used for further analysis or inference. Additionally, you can explore approximations for this integral under assumptions such as large $ r_s $ or small $ r_s $ regimes to obtain closed-form solutions.
